# Handle SES bounce and complaints with C# Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a C# application this is using Amazon SES to send emails. What I would like to do is call an endpoint in my application with a lambda function when I get a bounce or reply to an email. I have the following C# Lambda function, which works but there are two problems.
1. I can't figure out how to identify a failure.
2. I can't find the text of the message from the user.

```
        public async Task FunctionHandler(Amazon.Lambda.SimpleEmailEvents.SimpleEmailEvent emailEvent, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        foreach (Amazon.Lambda.SimpleEmailEvents.SimpleEmailEvent.SimpleEmailRecord record in emailEvent.Records)
        {
            Amazon.Lambda.SimpleEmailEvents.SimpleEmailEvent.SimpleEmailService sesRecord = record.Ses;
            LambdaLogger.Log($"Processing message {sesRecord.Mail.MessageId}.");
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    string messageId = sesRecord.Mail.MessageId;
                    string to = string.Empty;
                    if (sesRecord.Mail.Destination != null && sesRecord.Mail.Destination.Count > 0)
                    {
                        to = sesRecord.Mail.Destination.First();
                    }

                    StringContent requestContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { MessageId = messageId, To = to }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://xxxx", requestContent);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    string stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Request exception: {e.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this not the right approach?  I have also read about using SES and SNS to accomplish this, but I would like to avoid adding another layer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be setup as an automated process, that AWS has outlined here, and includes sample code (C#).
http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxJE1JNZ6T9JXK/-Handling-span-class-matches-Bounces-span-and-Complaints.pdf

Comment: I've seen that document and read it several times.  I am trying to avoid the complexity of another system (SQS).  If that is the route I have to take I will but Lambda seemed like a good alternative, unless I'm misunderstanding what Lambda is for.